# Поиск среднего значения однотипных элементов разных списков

Tags: python

Дано: словарь с ключом класса дата и значением список с 4 элементами типа:

```
weather = {
    datetime.date(1948, 1, 1): [51, 42, 0.47, True], 
    datetime.date(1948, 1, 2): [45, 36, 0.59, True],
    datetime.date(1948, 1, 3): [45, 35, 0.42, True],
    datetime.date(1948, 1, 4): [45, 34, 0.31, True], 
    datetime.date(1948, 1, 5): [45, 32, 0.17, True],
    datetime.date(1948, 1, 6): [48, 39, 0.44, True],
    ...
}
```

Задача создать новый словарь, который будет считать средние значения каждого элемента по году, например:

```
{
    2017: 
        [45.666666666666664, 34.333333333333336, 2.28, 9, 15]
}
```

Мой код:

```
def avg(l):
    return sum(l) / float(len(l))
for key in weather.keys():
    value = weather[key]

    #тут надо что-то написать, но у меня никак не выходит

    yearly_weather[key.year] = x
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать это при помощи стандартных инструментов, без использований pandas или numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime
from itertools import groupby
from statistics import mean

data = {datetime.date(1948, 1, 1): [51, 42, 0.47, True], datetime.date(1948, 1, 2): [45, 36, 0.59, True], datetime.date(1948, 1, 3): [45, 35, 0.42, True], datetime.date(1948, 1, 4): [45, 34, 0.31, True], datetime.date(1948, 1, 5): [45, 32, 0.17, True], datetime.date(1948, 1, 6): [48, 39, 0.44, True]}

groups = []
for k, g in groupby(data, lambda key: key.year):
    group_values = list(zip(*[data[key] for key in g]))  # -> [(51, 45, 45, 45, 45, 48), (42, 36, 35, 34, 32, 39),...
    group_means = [mean(val) for val in group_values[:3]]
    groups.append((k, group_means))

print(groups)  # -> [(1948, [46.5, 36.333333333333336, 0.39999999999999997])]
```

Comment: получился не словарь, а список с кортежами из числа и списка. примерно так надо предпоследнюю строку написать groups[k] = group_means. ну и поменять groups = [] на groups = {}