# Сравнение элементов в списках с выборкой

Tags: python, list, выборка

Вопрос такой, есть список с размерами деталей ( формата [ширина,высота,количество]) требуется найти одинаковые детали, и в отдельный список занести в формате [ширина, высота, количество(сумма одинаковых деталей)], тоесть найти одинаковые размеры и сложить их количество
Только начал изучать Python, поэтому интересует как правильно можно было организовать алгоритм решения.
Мое решение, понимаю костыль, но все же

```
def parsDataList():
sum=[]
b = [[466.4, 590.0, 2], [800.0, 590.0, 2], [465.4, 580.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 2],
     [800.0, 590.0, 2], [465.4, 580.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 1], [800.0, 590.0, 2],
     [465.4, 580.0, 6], [466.4, 590.0, 7]]

tmp = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    count = b[i][2]
    for x in b[
             i + 1:]:
        if b[i][0] == x[0] and b[i][1] == x[1] or b[i][1] == x[0] and b[i][0] == x[1]:
            count += x[2]
            x[0] = 0
            x[1] = 0
            x[2] = 0

    if b[i] != [0, 0, 0]:
        tmp.append(b[i][0])
        tmp.append(b[i][1])
        tmp.append(count)
        sum.append(tmp[:])
        tmp = []
print (sum)
```

Comment: если исходная и окончательная структура должны быть именно такой, то все норм. А для разнообразия посмотрите модуль collections  класс Counter

Answer (score 1):

Всего несколько дней назад, уже давали ответ на схожий вопрос. Будьте внимательнее, пожалуйста!
[Поиск среднего значения однотипных элементов разных списков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878342/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2/878362#878362)
Наверное разные варианты из одного задачника?

```
from itertools import groupby

#sum=[] # !!! не вводите переменные перекрывающие стандартные функции
b = [[466.4, 590.0, 2], [800.0, 590.0, 2], [465.4, 580.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 2],
     [800.0, 590.0, 2], [465.4, 580.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 1], [800.0, 590.0, 2],
     [465.4, 580.0, 6], [466.4, 590.0, 7]]

groups = []
b = sorted(b, key=lambda x: x[:2])
for k, g in groupby(b, lambda key: key[:2]):
    k.append(sum([it[2] for it in g]))
    groups.append(k)


print (groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант, когда не умеешь пользоваться встроенными библиотеками:

```
b = [[466.4, 590.0, 2], [800.0, 590.0, 2], [465.4, 580.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 2],
 [800.0, 590.0, 2], [465.4, 580.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 2], [466.4, 590.0, 1], [800.0, 590.0, 2],
 [465.4, 580.0, 6], [466.4, 590.0, 7]]

t, res = [[tuple(x[:2]), x[2]] for x in b], {}
for y in t:
    res[y[0]] = res[y[0]] + y[1] if y[0] in res else y[1]
print [[z[0], z[1], res[z]] for z in res]
# [[800.0, 590.0, 6], [466.4, 590.0, 16], [465.4, 580.0, 10]]
```